# How to parse characters in a single-quoted string?

Tags: php, hex, quotes

To get a double quoted string (which I cannot change) correctly parsed I have to do following:

```
$string = '15 Rose Avenue\n Irlam\n Manchester'; 
$string = str_replace('\n', "\n", $string);
print nl2br($string); // demonstrates that the \n's are now linebreak characters
```

So far, so good.
But in my given string there are characters like `\xC3\xA4`. There are many characters like this (beginning with \x..)
How can I get them correctly parsed as shown above with the linebreak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
$str = stripcslashes($str);
```

Comment: Nice. It is good to also provide a link to http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripcslashes.php, and mention that all '\xYY' here are hexadecimal character notations that the method can also handle C-like \n, \r ... and octal representations.

Answer (score -1):

You can escape a `\` in single quotes:

```
$string = str_replace('\\n', "\n", $string);
```

But you're going to have a lot of potential replaces if you need to do `\\xC3`, etc.... best use a `preg_replace_callback()` with a function(callback) to translate them to bytes